# Calculate the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the matrix $B=A^{-1}+μ\cdot I_ν$ with $μ \in R$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $λ$ be an eigenvalue of an $ν\times ν $ invertible matrix $A$ with an eigenvector $x$. Calculate the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of the matrix $B=A^{-1}+μ\cdot I_ν$ with $μ \in R$

So, as we know as the matrix $A$ is invertible, we can assume that all the eigenvalues are $\ne 0$. As a result, we have that $λ \ne 0$ and also $Ax=λx$. That's what I know.

So, how can I proceed so as to solve this problem? Can anyone give me a thorough solution/explanation of this problem because I do not have previous experience in this type of exercises?

**Thanks, in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Ax=\lambda x$ and $A$ is invertible we have that $\lambda^{-1}x=A^{-1}x$. So we see that the eigenvectors of $A$ are eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$, whereas the eigenvalues need to be inverted. Then to answer your question, apply such an eigenvector to $B$, that is $(A^{-1}+\mu I_{\nu})x=(\lambda^{-1}+\mu)x$.